# Is it possible to make a instance null in the class itself?

Tags: java, c#

can we make a instance reference null in the class itself?
like bellow:

```
public class ClassA{
    public void clear(){
        //make this class be null
    }
}

ClassA a = new ClassA();
a.clear();
//now a == null
```

can we implement this methord in C# or Java

Comment: I am pretty sure you can only dump all objects by setting them to null in your class and garbage collecting. Making it null has to be done by the variable holder

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21283346/how-to-set-the-instance-to-null-inside-class and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562258/setting-an-object-to-null-within-its-own-class-definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer: No.**

Longer answer:

Instances cannot be `null` at all. Variables that are typed as references to the class can be set to `null`, but not instances. There can be many variables referring to the same instance. The instance has no way of knowing about those variables, so there's no way for it to reach out and set them to `null`.

Instead, you could have a method that returns `null` with the return type of the class:

```
public ClassA clear() {
    return null;
}
```

...which the caller could use

```
foo = foo.clear();
```

But it doesn't really serve any purpose, the caller could just as easily do

```
foo = null;
```

---

Side note:

In .Net (since you mention C#), you might look at the [`IDisposable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface.

In Java, you might look at [`AutoCloseable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html).

Comment: sorry ,I didn't describe it clearly. I modified the question.can this be implemented?

Comment: @Yizhi: That's what I'm talking about the answer above. No, you can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ClassA
{
  private ClassA obj = new ClassA();
  public void clear(){
        obj = null;
    }
}
```

Is this what you are expecting, References of an object can be set to null.